# Group IP addresses belonging to the same /24 network

Tags: bash, ip, sort

I have a file containing a list of both IPv4 addresses and /24 networks.

The IP addresses are already unique and sorted by all four octets.

I would like to use bash to group the addresses that belong to the same /24 subnet (if there is more than one address in that subnet), otherwise, I want to keep the IP addresses as they are in the list.

For example:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.20.0.0/24
10.30.10.1
10.30.10.2
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.5
192.168.30.0/24
192.168.50.3
```

Desired output:

```
10.0.0.0/24
10.20.0.0/24
10.30.10.0/24
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.5
192.168.30.0/24
192.168.50.3
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you follow the prescribed network structure: `Class A`, `Class B`, `Class C`, etc.?    Or can an IP address like `10.10.0.1` belong to a `/8`, `/16`, `/24`, etc. network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to use each `/24` network as a key that stores an array of the subnets on that network. Output is then generated based on the length of each array. However, this method has the disadvantage that it **does not support streamed processing**.

For reference only

#### AWK

```bash
awk '{
    if (index($0, "/") > 0) { ip_map[$0] = "" } 
    else {
        split($0, parts, ".")
        network = parts[1]"."parts[2]"."parts[3]".0/24"
        if (network in ip_map) { ip_map[network] = ip_map[network]" "$0 } 
    else { ip_map[network] = $0 }
    }
}
END {
    for (k in ip_map) {
        if (ip_map[k] == "" || split(ip_map[k], arr) > 1) { print k } 
    else { print ip_map[k] }
    }
}' | sort -n
```

#### bash

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# or use `readarray -t` to read input from a file

ips=(
    "10.0.0.1"
    "10.0.0.2"
    "10.0.0.3"
    "10.20.0.0/24"
    "10.30.10.1"
    "10.30.10.2"
    "192.168.0.1"
    "192.168.1.5"
    "192.168.30.0/24"
    "192.168.50.3"
)

declare -A ip_map

for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$ip" == *"/"* ]]; then
        ip_map["$ip"]=null
    else
    network=$(echo "$ip" | { IFS="."; read a b c d; echo "$a.$b.$c.0/24"; })
        if [[ ${ip_map[$network]+_} ]]; then
            ip_map["$network"]+=" $ip"
        else
            ip_map["$network"]="$ip"
        fi
    fi
done

for k in "${!ip_map[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${ip_map[$k]}" == null || $(echo "${ip_map[$k]}" | wc -w) -gt 1 ]]; then
        echo "$k"
    else
        echo "${ip_map[$k]}"
    fi
done | sort -n
```

#### Python

```py
import ipaddress
ips = [
    "10.0.0.1",
    "10.0.0.2",
    "10.0.0.3",
    "10.20.0.0/24",
    "10.30.10.1",
    "10.30.10.2",
    "192.168.0.1",
    "192.168.1.5",
    "192.168.30.0/24",
    "192.168.50.3",
]
ip_map = {}

for ip in ips:
    if "/" in ip:
        ip_map[ip] = None
    else:
        network = ipaddress.ip_network(ip + "/24", strict=False)
        try:
            ip_map[network].append(ip)
        except KeyError:
            ip_map[network] = [ip]
        
for k, v in ip_map.items():
    if v is None or len(v) > 1:
        print(k)
    elif len(v) == 1:
        print(v[0])
```